# jQuery set initial speed of fadein

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want this div to load instantly on page load (or thereabouts) and then automatically refresh every 10 seconds. 
This is what I have, which refreshes every 10 seconds but doesn’t load instantly.

Can I set the initial refresh to say 100ms and then after that refresh every 10 seconds?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var auto_refresh = setInterval(
    function ()
    {
      $('#now-playing').load('now-playing-info.php').fadeIn("fast");
    }
  , 10000); // refresh every 10000 milliseconds
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to run it once first.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function() {
    function nowPLaying()
    {
        $('#now-playing').load('now-playing-info.php').fadeIn("fast");
    }
    nowPLaying();
    var auto_refresh = setInterval(nowPLaying, 10000); // refresh every 10000 milliseconds  
}); 

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just load it, then set the interval:

```
$('#now-playing').load('now-playing-info.php').fadeIn("fast");
var auto_refresh = setInterval(function (){
    $('#now-playing').load('now-playing-info.php').fadeIn("fast");
}, 10000);
```

You could forgo the whole `setInterval()` for a [`setTimeout()`](http://jsfiddle.net/JcNZJ/) instead. For instance:

```
var loadNowPlayingInfo = function(){
    $('#now-playing').load('now-playing-info.php').fadeIn("fast");
    setTimeout(loadNowPlayingInfo, 10000);
}
loadNowPlayingInfo(); // Calls the function, then starts your interval
```

I would consider the second the better option. Note as well, you might want to but the `setTimeout()` in the `success` handler of the `.load()` so it waits for the previous to load.